# Is it possible to set a CSS class' ":after" pseudo-element content property to the value of a text input on the same page

Tags: html, css

I was talking about something to a friend about HTML and I wondered if it would be possible to dynamically display the value of a HTML text input somewhere else on that page using just CSS? This is a hypothetical question by the way, I can't see it having any real practical use, but take the following code HTML / CSS :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>I like this world</title>
</head>
<style>
div:after {
    content: "Hello";
}
</style>
<body>
    <input type="text">
    <!-- the content shown will be "Hello" -->
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The div tag would display the "Hello" string as we use the `:after` pseudo-element to generate content in the div. Would it be possible to use CSS selectors so that the div shows the content/value of the input as the user types? The code example below won't work but I was thinking of something like this...

```
<style>
div:after {
    content: input[value];
}
</style>
```

I'm currently trying this at home to determine if it is possible, if anyone else has tried it and can tell me if it is or isn't possible I would be most appreciative.

If I haven't explained myself well please state so and I shall reword.

Comment: You would need Javascript for this. CSS is loaded on page load, so it's not going to change once you enter something into the input.

Comment: Well, we are able to use e.g. `content: attr(href)` to display the URL of a link in print stylesheets, but this does not help us here. Also, even that option does not update after page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without javascript.

But you can show an attribute:

```
<div data-text="Show this text"></div>

<style>
div:after { 
    content: attr(data-text);
}
</style>
```